# Kafka group re-balancing after consumer failed. org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm running a Kafka cluster with 4 nodes, 1 producer and 1 consumer. It was working fine until consumer failed. Now after I restart the consumer, it starts consuming new messages but after some minutes it throws this error:

```
[WARN ]: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Auto offset commit failed for group eventGroup: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

And it starts consuming the same messages again and loops forever.

I increased session timeout, tried to change group id and it still does the same thing.

Also is the client version of Kafka consumer a big deal?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to decouple the consumer and the processing logic, to start with. E.g. let the Kafka consumer only poll messages and maybe after sanitizing the messages (if necessary) delegate the actual processing of each record to a separate thread, then see if the same error is still occurring. The error says, you're spending too much time between the subsequent polls, so this might resolve your issue. Also, please mention the version of Kafka you're using. Kafka had a different heartbeat management policy before version 0.10 which could make this issue easier to reproduce.